# Calculate $3\cdot 4+ 4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Question: calculate $3\cdot 4+ 4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$  and $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

I don't really understand how to approach this problem, any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: calculate $3 \cdot 4 + 4$ and then find the rest of the division by 7 and by 10

Comment: alright that sounds logical , btw a off-topic question : is 1/5 multiplicative inverse of 5 ? am i thinking right ?

Comment: @humble24 Depends what you mean by 1/5. If you mean the rational number $\frac{1}{5}$, then it is the multiplicative inverse of the rational number $5$. If you mean the rational $\frac{1}{5}$, it is not the multiplicative inverse of the element $5 \in \mathbb{Z}_7$. If you mean "the multiplicative inverse of 5", then of course it's the multiplicative inverse of 5.

Comment: honestly i was aiming at  multiplicative inverse of 5∈Z11 , how do i find it then ?

Comment: @humble24 Use extended Euclidean algorithm to find $a,b$ that satisfy $5a + 11b = 1$, which then means $5a \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$.

Comment: allright , thanks all :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to calculate this, simply do the calculation and then reduce the answer mod 7 or 10:

$$
3\cdot 4+4=16\equiv 2 \text{ (mod }7\text{)} \\ 3\cdot 4+4=16\equiv 6 \text{ (mod }10\text{)}
$$

Regarding your question in the comments, $\frac{1}{5}$ generally means the inverse of 5 which of course depends on what ring you are in. The inverse of 5 in $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ can be found naively by multiplying 5 by every element of $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ until you find one that multiplies to give 1. You can do it systematically by finding solutions to $11x+5y=1$ using the Euclidean algorithm. The value you obtain for $y$ will be the multiplicative inverse of 5 in $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$. In this case you get $y=-2\equiv 9$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about it. You can do each operation in $\mathbb{Z}$ and convert to $\mathbb{Z}_7$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ as needed, or do all the operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, as the case may be) in $\mathbb{Z}$ and then convert to $\mathbb{Z}_7$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ at the end.

For example, you can first do $3 \times 4 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$ and then $5 + 4 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$. Or you can do $3 \times 4 + 4 = 16 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$, you get the same result either way.